# Laravel mix not working

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-mix

after running command "npm run dev", paths of complied assets are not loading.Am i missing some step ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before? Show your webpack.mix.js.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to autoload `jQuery`?

You can follow the steps here in this [docs](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/autoloading.md).